# Adding sun-cmp-mappings.xml file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-2.x, cmp

I am creating CMP beans using Netbeans 6.9.1. 
Everything worked fine until I added the sun-cmp-mappings.xml file to the conf folder and comment out line 59 in project.properties. I got this error
 **Cannot deploy application 'myproject-ejb' with CMP beans: cmp-resource is not defined for this module. The minimum requirement for a cmp-resource is to specify the jndi-name of a jdbc-resource or a persistence-manager-factory-resource to be used with the beans.**
I removed the file and it worked again, but I really need to map the name of tables and columns.
 Can anyone helps me please ?

Comment: where can I find the sun-cmp-mappings.xml of NetBeans to modify it instead of adding a new one ?

Answer (score 1):

adding <cmp-resource> tag in the sun-ejb-jar.xml to solve the problem.